# From .Net to Java

Tags: c#, java, .net

Which would be the best way to write the same code in Java?:

```
 Array.Resize(ref DCamposGraficoOperaciones[index].DatosMeses, 12);
```

I have this code in C# and I have to put it on in Java. Thanks so much. I have a method called resizeDatosMeses in Java to resize the array but when I try to do it in this way:

```
DCamposGraficoOperaciones[index].getDatosMeses()=resizeDatosMeses(DCamposGraficoOperaciones[index].getDatosMeses(), 12)
```

I have a mistake which is: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, please could you advice me?

Thanks so much

Comment: "I have a mistake" - what does wrong? Does it fail to compile? If so, what error do you get? (I suspect you will, but the thing it to learn how to ask better questions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* you want:

```
DCamposGraficoOperaciones[index].setDatosMeses(
    resizeDatosMeses(DCamposGraficoOperaciones[index].getDatosMeses(), 12));
```

You can't *assign* to the result of a method call, which is what you were trying to do before.

I would *strongly* encourage you to break this line into two separate statements - and also start following Java naming conventions, which would prohibit `DCamposGraficoOperaciones` as a variable name.

Also, it's not clear why you're resizing an array to start with, but in both .NET and Java you may well be better off using a higher-level abstraction, e.g. `List<T>` in .NET or `ArrayList<T>` in Java.

Comment: I would love to do that if I didn't have to use a WS because this method is part of a WS and the ArrayList is not supported by the WS.

Answer (score 0):

In java you cant re-size arrays. You can use ArrayList and you can add any number of values to it.

Comment: You can't resize arrays in .NET either. But you can write a method which takes an array reference and returns a new array reference, which is what the OP appears to already have.

Comment: Really? ArrayList seems to resize arrays just fine. :-) (okay, so behind the scenes it does some intricate "magic", but still!)